# Validation upload image file PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image, validation, file-upload

I have problem when i want to upload file, the script have a validation for types image file like jpg, png, When I upload the image file successful process, but when I try to upload different file types like doc, pdf etc. appear notification/alert if the file type is wrong but the data file still managed to get into the database and folder, the script working just for announce the types file is wrong but still save the data...

This my Script

```
$image=$_FILES['upload']['name'];
$typeGambar = array('image/bmp', 'image/gif', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png');
if(!in_array($_FILES['upload']['type'][$i],$typeGambar)){ 
            echo"<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=home.php?p=product'>";
            }
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `t_product` (`id_product`,`product`,`category`,`material`,`ink`,`price`,`status`,`date`) VALUES ('$idproduct','$product','$category','$material','$ink','$price','$status',NOW());");

if ($sql) {
    $last_id = mysql_insert_id();
    foreach ($_POST['size'] as $select){
        $sql2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `t_productsize` (`id_product`,`id_size`) VALUES ('$last_id','$select');");
    }
    $total = count($_FILES['upload']['name']);

    // Loop through each file
    for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
      //Get the temp file path
      $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
      $fileError = $_FILES['upload']['error'][$i];    
      $typeGambar = array('image/bmp', 'image/gif', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png');
      if(!in_array($_FILES['upload']['type'][$i],$typeGambar)){ 
        echo'<script>
            alert("Failed insert data!!");
            </script>';
        }
        elseif($fileSize=$_FILES['gambar']['size']< 20000 || $fileError < 20000){
      //Make sure we have a filepath
      if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
        $newfilename= date('dmYHis').str_replace(" ", "", basename($_FILES["upload"]["name"]));
        //Setup our new file path
        $newFilePath = "images_product/".$newfilename . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
        $nameImage = $newfilename . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];


        //Upload the file into the temp dir
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

          //Handle other code here
        $sql3 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `t_productimage` (`id_product`,`image`) VALUES ('$last_id','$nameImage');");
        }
      }
    }
    }
    echo '<script>
        window.location="home.php?p=product";
        </script>';}

    else {
        echo'<script>
            alert("Failed insert data!!");
            </script>';
    }
```

Big Thanks for responsed

Comment: Your script issues a meta refresh, but that does not mean your script ends there - the whole script is processed first, before the result is send to the browser. Either put everything else in an `else` branch, or use die/exit to exit the script after the meta refresh code was output. Btw. the mysql extenstion has been deprecated for a long time now, you should not be using it any more. And your code looks open to SQL injection.

Comment: yes u right, I'm currently studying mysqli, thks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$image=$_FILES['upload']['name'];
$typeGambar = array('image/bmp', 'image/gif', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png');
if(!in_array($_FILES['upload']['type'][$i],$typeGambar)){
            echo"<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=home.php?p=product'>"; }
else {
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `t_product` (`id_product`,`product`,`category`,`material`,`ink`,`price`,`status`,`date`) VALUES ('$idproduct','$product','$category','$material','$ink','$price','$status',NOW());");

if ($sql) {

$last_id = mysql_insert_id();
foreach ($_POST['size'] as $select){
    $sql2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `t_productsize` (`id_product`,`id_size`) VALUES ('$last_id','$select');");
}
$total = count($_FILES['upload']['name']);

// Loop through each file
for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
  //Get the temp file path
  $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
  $fileError = $_FILES['upload']['error'][$i];    
  $typeGambar = array('image/bmp', 'image/gif', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png');
  if(!in_array($_FILES['upload']['type'][$i],$typeGambar)){ 
    echo'<script>
        alert("Failed insert data!!");
        </script>';
    }
    elseif($fileSize=$_FILES['gambar']['size']< 20000 || $fileError < 20000){
  //Make sure we have a filepath
  }
  else {
  if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
    $newfilename= date('dmYHis').str_replace(" ", "", basename($_FILES["upload"]["name"]));
    //Setup our new file path
    $newFilePath = "images_product/".$newfilename . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
    $nameImage = $newfilename . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];


    //Upload the file into the temp dir
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

      //Handle other code here
    $sql3 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `t_productimage` (`id_product`,`image`) VALUES ('$last_id','$nameImage');");
    }}
  }
}
}
echo '<script>
    window.location="home.php?p=product";
    </script>';}

else {
    echo'<script>
        alert("Failed insert data!!");
        </script>';
}}
```

- NOTE : You just wrong in your logic.

Comment: Your right but you might want to point out the missing `}else{` that you added... just a thought.  `if(!in_array($_FILES['upload']['type'][$i],$typeGambar)){ ... }else{...`

Comment: thks for responsed, i try your script but appear "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\nulfnew\a-panel\pages\product-add.php on line 202"

T-T

Comment: Assuming you to understand my * NOTE

Comment: I am not try your code in my project, so just fix your own code as insert closing tag like this :  elseif($fileSize=$_FILES['gambar']['size']< 20000 || $fileError < 20000){
      //Make sure we have a filepath
      }